# Cannot find name 'MediaRecorder' even though I've installed @types/dom-mediacapture-record

Tags: typescript, types

I'm trying to create an audio recording app using react and typescript. TO record user audio, the `MediaRecorder` class needs to be used. Based on [this issue] (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34728), I installed `@types/dom-mediacapture-record` but it stills shows an error.

Code:

```
const recordAudio = () => {
        navigator.getUserMedia(
            { audio: true },
            (stream) => {
                // Error is here
                const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            (err) => {}
        );
    };
```

Error:

```
Cannot find name 'MediaRecorder'. Did you mean 'mediaRecorder'?ts(2552)
```

Please help me out here, what am I missing?

Comment: If you try to create an audio record, there is no use in just installing types but try 3rd party library or api such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder